# url containing query string in vlc

Tags: vlc-media-player, http, url

I am trying to open a network stream in VLC. The URL of the content is of the form

`http://192.168.0.1:80/content/recordings?dataid=myid&key1=value1&key2=value2`

Whenever I append the query string vlc fails to open the url. Please help me with the right format to use query strings in url

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to know why `&` doesn't work here but `%26` does?

Answer (score 0):

The right format to append the query string when an URL is used in browser, VLC (or) any web application is

`http://192.168.0.1:80/content/recordings?dataid=myid&key1=value1&key2=value`

Hence the format in the question is correct. The reason the VLC wasn't able to handle the URL is the way in which the server handles the given query string had some issues.